# solving the determinants of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

So i was given this question

Evaluate by first adding all other rows to the first row

My solution:

$
det
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
x-1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & -3& x-2 \\
-2 & x & -2
\end{array} } \right]
$ = $
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
x-1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & -3& x-2 \\
-2 & x & -2
\end{array} } \right]
$ = $(x-1)
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -5& x-4 \\
-2 & x & -2
\end{array} } \right]
$ = $(x-1)
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
-5 & x-4\\
x+2 & 0& 
\end{array} } \right]
$=$(x-2)(x-4)(x+2)$ = $(x-2)(x^2-2x-8)$

Is this correct?

Comment: Please make separate questions into separate posts.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct. You may add any row to any other row without changing the determinant. Using your hint you would get

$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
x-1 & 2 & 3\\
2   &-3 &x-2 \\
-2  & x & -2
\end{bmatrix} = \det\begin{bmatrix}
x-1 & x-1 & x-1\\
2   &-3 &x-2 \\
-2  & x & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now we can subtract the first column from the second and third and get

$${} = \det\begin{bmatrix}
x-1 & 0 & 0\\
2   &-5 &x-4 \\
-2  & x+2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we can use the Laplace formula on the first row, because there are a lot of zeros and get

$${}=(x-1)\det\begin{bmatrix}-5 & x-4\\x+2 & 0\end{bmatrix}
= -(x-1)(x-4)(x+2). $$